# How do I add a wildcard option as an available option for a SSRS paramater?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add in a wild card selection to my one of my dropdowns within a SSRS report that passes in a "%" to the query it is linked to but has a label of "All Vendors" to the end user.

Highlighted is where I would like to see "All Vendors"
[image]

I attempted to use the available values option as opposed to the get values from a query option with the idea that I could specify an expression that returns the same values as the query and then specify a single value as described above. But when I tried to do this I received an error like:
 "A value expression used for the report parameter "VND" refers to a field. Fields cannot be used in report expressions."

The expression I used was:
 =Multilookup(Split(Fields!ve_name.Value, ",")

Available Values Window

[image]

Could someone tell me if theres an easier way to accomplish this or if my syntax is just bad and that this is the best way to do this?

Comment: When you create the dataset for the param union on a "All Vendors" , NULL Add a sort to make it the first option. Then in your proc Check if it's NULL. YourColum = ISNULL(@Vendor,YourColum)

Comment: Why don't you just use a multiple valued parameter? Multiple valued parameter include a `Select All` option. Check [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/)

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, thats exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a simple solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [alejandro zuleta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2647648/alejandro-zuleta), mentions in a comment,

> Why don't you just use a multiple valued parameter? Multiple valued parameter include a Select All option. Check [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters)

Using a multiple valued parameter helped.